# Javascript interval and iframe

Tags: javascript

I have an asp.net page that opens a page in jqueryWindow (iframe) that loads some contents and a button. When the user clicks the button, I call a function to do some work and a setInterval function at the end of click function. The interval function works fine and  while the window(iFrame) is opened, when I close the window, the interval stops in Firefox and this error will show in the console:

```
attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope
```

However it works it IE.

Any ideas?

later desc :
the interval is function is in parent. But I used firebug that surprisingly saw that the function is going to be called in its interval but it returns error and sometimes works fine. :O

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has garbage-collected the iframe's scope due to it not existing anymore. Other browsers may not do things the same way.

Try calling `top.setInterval(...)` instead of just `setInterval(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is being called from the iframe, it should not run at all after the iframe is closed since its global context has been destroyed. I would expect the function to simply not run in either browser and not to throw an error either.

Perhaps it's a bug? Anyhow, as Kolink says, trying calling it from the parent (top), but you will (should?) get errors if it's trying to reference objects or variables that were in the pop-up's scope.

Comment: the interval is function is in parent. But I used firebug that surprisingly saw that the function is going to be called in its interval but it returns error and sometimes works fine. :O